# Clone a <div> including select lists in JQuery UI selctmenu doesn't clone event handlers

Tags: jquery

I used the Jquery UI select menu widget (http://jsfiddle.net/fnagel/GXtpC/) in order to wrap text in the select options of the dropdown lists with long text.

After these select lists there is a button. When the button is clicked, a div
including these select lists and some other fields is cloned. In the cloned div
, the select options are not displayed and the dropdown list doesn't open.

I guess that when the click event is trigerred it doesn't trigger any events on that element and  I need your support on how to build the integration manually.

Here is the code in JQuery for the button click event:

```
$(function() {
   var result = $('#content'); 
   $('#add').on('click', function () {
      var original = $('#full');
      var copy = original.clone();
      copy.val(original.val());
      result.empty().append(copy);
   });
});
```

Here is a part of the HTML code:

```
<div id="full">
    <label for="select1" tabindex="0">Select1:</label><br><br>
    <select name="select1" id="select1" >
        <option value="0" selected>Select from the list</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1:Long text is included......</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2:Long text is included......</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3:Long text is included.....</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <label for="select2" tabindex="0">Select2:</label><br><br>
    <select name="select2" id="select2">
        <option value="0" selected>Select from the list</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1:Long text is included......</option>
        <option value="2">Option 1:Long text is included......</option>
        <option value="3">Option 1:Long text is included......</option>
    </select><br><br>       
</div>  
<div id="content"></div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" /><br><br>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `.clone(true)`, https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents

Comment: @Satpal When  Ι use .clone(true) and try to open the  select list of the cloned div the focus goes on the corresponding select of the original div.

Comment: You need to modify the `id` as they must be unique. Also update `for="select1"` attribute for same reason

Comment: I also tried to replace all the ids with classes but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please advice me how to update the ids of the cloned div?